# Emberjs novalidate on form input

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to add the novalidate option to an email form helper (and others) and I can't get it to work. I have tried the following:

```
  {{input type='email' placeholder='Email' value=email novalidate='novalidate'}}
  {{input type='email' placeholder='Email' value=email novalidate='true'}}
  {{input type='email' placeholder='Email' value=email novalidate}}
  {{input type='email' placeholder='Email' value=email 'novalidate'}}
```

Is this a tag that is unsupported by ember? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

The `novalidate` attribute belongs on a `<form>` element, not on an `<input>`.  Besides this, if you want to bind an arbitrary attribute to a `TextField`, then do this:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-some-attribute']
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. So is it kind of an all or nothing thing? I can have html validations on all of the form or none of the form?

Comment: I believe that to be the case.